# Installing asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having trouble installing asp.net MVC 5. Here are things I did before approaching for help.

Attempt 1: 
I tried to use this link which opened WebInstaller but it says "Microsoft Web Platform Installer couldn't fine the product you tried to install. Either the link you clicked is incorrect or you may be 
overriding your feed with a different feed."

https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids

Attempt 2:
Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Frameworks 2013.1 - Visual Studio 2012
https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids

Error: This product only supports English versions of Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.

Products I have:

Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 5 RC

Visual Studio 2012 Shell (integrated)

Comment: Try downloading Visual Studio 2015 Community and using that.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, I solve downloading by direct link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/7/2F7FA65F-E8BB-42A2-99A2-7F355225D30C/AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe

Hope solve to you to.

{}'s

Rodrigo Reis